# Application crushes after onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

In my android application I have one problem that I can't resolve already 3 days. I read a lot of posts and answers but still can't find a my solution.

My problem is when I press home button and return to application after long time later it crushes (NullPointerException).

This is my DiscountDataFragment

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discount_data, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.discountCardListView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        View v = View.inflate(mActivity,R.layout.search_view,null);
        mListView.addHeaderView(v);
        mSearchEditText =(MGEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
        mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.iplus).setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```

And this is exception that I have

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
            at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16459)
            at com.example.android.BS.fragments.discount.DiscountDataFragment.onCreateView(DiscountDataFragment.java:45)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1844)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:519)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I couldn't understand why it crushes and what's the problem that application cannot inflate view after returning long time sleep.

1. What is the problem here that crash application?
2. What another solution can you offer for resolving this issue?

Comment: please indicate line 45 @ `DiscountDataFragment` and change `View.inflate(mActivity,R.layout.search_view,null);` to `view.inflate(mActivity,R.layout.search_view,null);`, with `v` on view

Comment: I tried this way too but it crushed again with same exception

Comment: Are you initializing `mActivity` object ?

Comment: public DiscountDataFragment(DefaultActivity pActivity) {
        mActivity = pActivity;
    }

Comment: line 45 is  View v = view.inflate(mActivity,R.layout.search_view,null);

Comment: Well, I'm confused.  Which line, exactly, is line 45?  You understand that the stack trace references the exact line where the exception is thrown?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan maybe mActivity becoming null after some time? Is that can be?

Comment: if you use with `V` so you must get error, but if you use `v` two possibility exists, 1- `view` is null , 2- `mActivity` is null, so check those.

Comment: Szymon answer is correct, but also avoid creating fragment with parametric constructor. Fragment's constructor should always be empty by default. Initialize your fragment with static newInstance() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you come back to your view, your activity may not be created yet when `onCreateView()` is called.

What you should do is to move all the code that depends on the activity to [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. According to the documentation this method is:

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated.

You can then use your activity.

Also, there's no need to pass the activity to the fragment, as you can always get it using `getActivity()` method. Not passing your activity will also limit your chance of creating a memory leak.